# Delphi XML Data Binding doesn't load correctly

Tags: xml, delphi

I use XML Data Binding to create the interfaces for this [XSD](http://www.sii.cl/factura_electronica/schema_dte.zip), it a very complex one. The funny thing is that I generate the XML file like a charm but when I save it to file and try to load later it only loads part of the properties to the objects but if I do MyXML.XML it shows the whole XML including the "empty" properties like KeyInfo.KeyValue.RSAKeyValue.Modulus. How can I force it to reload all properties values? Resync method does nothing.

```
var
  xDTE : IXMLEnvioDTE;
  Modulus : AnsiString;
  s : IXMLSignatureType_ds;
.....
xDTE := LoadEnvioDTE('h:\ENVIO_DTE_379791.xml');
s := xDTE.Signature;
Modulus := s.KeyInfo.KeyValue.RSAKeyValue.Modulus;
```

This is an XML example:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<EnvioDTE xmlns="http://www.sii.cl/SiiDte" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sii.cl/SiiDte EnvioDTE_v10.xsd">
 <SetDTE ID="SetDoc">
  <Caratula version="1.0">
   <RutEmisor>88888888-8</RutEmisor>
   <RutEnvia>8414240-9</RutEnvia>
   <RutReceptor>76425071-0</RutReceptor>
   <FchResol>2003-05-16</FchResol>
   <NroResol>0</NroResol>
   <TmstFirmaEnv>2015-04-29T17:11:14</TmstFirmaEnv>
   <SubTotDTE>
    <TpoDTE>33</TpoDTE>
    <NroDTE>2</NroDTE>
   </SubTotDTE>
  </Caratula>
 <DTE xmlns="http://www.sii.cl/SiiDte" version="1.0">
 <Documento ID="T33">
  <Encabezado>
   <IdDoc>
    <TipoDTE>33</TipoDTE>
    <Folio>52612</Folio>
    <FchEmis>2015-04-29</FchEmis>
   </IdDoc>
   <Emisor>
    <RUTEmisor>88888888-8</RUTEmisor>
    <RznSoc>EMPRESA DE PRUEBA</RznSoc>
    <GiroEmis>Informatica</GiroEmis>
    <Acteco>1</Acteco>
    <CdgSIISucur>59529595</CdgSIISucur>
    <DirOrigen>Teatinos 120</DirOrigen>
    <CmnaOrigen>Santiago</CmnaOrigen>
    <CiudadOrigen>Santiago</CiudadOrigen>
   </Emisor>
   <Receptor>
    <RUTRecep>76425071-0</RUTRecep>
    <RznSocRecep>MEDIVEN SPA</RznSocRecep>
    <GiroRecep>Comercial</GiroRecep>
    <DirRecep>Santiago</DirRecep>
    <CmnaRecep>Santiago</CmnaRecep>
    <CiudadRecep>Santiago</CiudadRecep>
   </Receptor>
   <Totales>
    <MntNeto>15888</MntNeto>
    <TasaIVA>19</TasaIVA>
    <IVA>3018</IVA>
    <MntTotal>18906</MntTotal>
   </Totales>
  </Encabezado>
  <Detalle>
   <NroLinDet>1</NroLinDet>
   <NmbItem>SET INTERCAMBIO NUMERO 379791</NmbItem>
   <QtyItem>6</QtyItem>
   <PrcItem>2648</PrcItem>
   <MontoItem>15888</MontoItem>
  </Detalle>
  <TED version="1.0">
   <DD>
    <RE>88888888-8</RE>
    <TD>33</TD>
    <F>52612</F>
    <FE>2015-04-29</FE>
    <RR>76425071-0</RR>
    <RSR>MEDIVEN SPA</RSR>
    <MNT>18906</MNT>
    <IT1>SET INTERCAMBIO NUMERO 379791</IT1>
    <CAF version="1.0">
     <DA>
      <RE>88888888-8</RE>
      <RS>EMPRESA DE PRUEBA</RS>
      <TD>33</TD>
      <RNG>
       <D>17479</D>
       <H>17901</H>
      </RNG>
      <FA>2004-03-30</FA>
      <RSAPK>
       <M>umn8PR3gbC1L3CFheZb5Woh2bj51lvaN2OnwFdTncKXFutekvIAxPmso9DRhgQKJOjlKS1TEKxvzPAYIeEf3tw==</M>
       <E>Aw==</E>
      </RSAPK>
      <IDK>1</IDK>
     </DA>
     <FRMA algoritmo="SHA1withRSA">FVGanT5jYLSopnBQt7+t48aoLtKTYtFZHCV3c2Z2V3XAdExCke7XXONn9N4Lq1BPR24vnH/qCyvIxaYBVCtEMw==</FRMA>
    </CAF>
    <TSTED>2015-04-29T17:11:14</TSTED>
   </DD>
   <FRMT algoritmo="SHA1withRSA">V+YvYUaHFLHuOVg/n5aRxNSgcTkFj2DbGvlH5iyema8h42BNil8f7ewbk7rr5V+a1ShBHcXxU9DjDHWFnQ9p2w==</FRMT>
  </TED>
  <TmstFirma>2015-04-29T17:11:14</TmstFirma>
 </Documento>
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<SignedInfo>
<CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
<SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
<Reference URI="#T33">
<Transforms>
<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
</Transforms>
<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<DigestValue>9zYkvTn3fSLBk2Rw5CkEM98Yjho=</DigestValue>
</Reference>
</SignedInfo>
<SignatureValue>
oSFxIeWfVisGJCmS3/dToiK/SM3e3Ht5at7AqVYpOBzuBCfpsAsnnYXHsNC8wXfKTb4BvAvPS/56
Tg2Y3C1twBbMPWZ2cjR9JB0wCHO8X0lGjRIl/VrJAy85puy+Qi6bEgUboIZVN/XNrC0tDniRfweN
WaoHs6EHz/3+HCLU1/8jAxgUzi155lvFJc7Uj7KdkuMb16q9241F0JXhjBZ/TsgeaKLOiZfFWz9Q
RGraiTP00H1+LF5B1o7yGaUODN/hq9UEBTt+C6kVSPhtSta1mzQ2twhlliIAA7WA8k2m2t1iZ84r
YW24RMmKLwqLbjPDRSGRQJwT2zhaqg2hpeFmCA==
</SignatureValue>
<KeyInfo>
<KeyValue>
<RSAKeyValue>
<Modulus>
xUg5RWGM6yKTu1hctQ0J9VZtr6+7VOQ75lDq7MeqxDTJgkHxO+P49GV/hRjLv3rCXvo9JBM8AKj5
U+/uue5OE6PgeqdS+M7HBF4ieD33wVsRYWuu2TLrw+/DRd6yEs61mPVRLDrIqjxxpa41VUAfwPXV
ksCZ7RNklyfSa5D+Zm6sx3v5kGPylWVpdW+k3BFYmUCW2j1rjGb5X9zV9Egi2VGe2SGsYLNu1aJS
HHAIPc+COJIBMENga/syQSNF2l4/GNUkn84RnlW5P75rPg6Oa+y2UwfUgmgrCeMcyJJKDMy6heqm
6huvgaxOTr9DZqWkxJYW5GGWTUUiq64JB3EjOQ==
</Modulus>
<Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
</RSAKeyValue>
</KeyValue>
<X509Data>
<X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate>
</X509Data>
</KeyInfo>
</Signature></DTE><DTE xmlns="http://www.sii.cl/SiiDte" version="1.0">
 <Documento ID="T35">
  <Encabezado>
   <IdDoc>
    <TipoDTE>33</TipoDTE>
    <Folio>52613</Folio>
    <FchEmis>2013-06-21</FchEmis>
   </IdDoc>
   <Emisor>
    <RUTEmisor>88888888-8</RUTEmisor>
    <RznSoc>EMPRESA DE PRUEBA</RznSoc>
    <GiroEmis>Informatica</GiroEmis>
    <Acteco>1</Acteco>
    <CdgSIISucur>59529595</CdgSIISucur>
    <DirOrigen>Teatinos 120</DirOrigen>
    <CmnaOrigen>Santiago</CmnaOrigen>
    <CiudadOrigen>Santiago</CiudadOrigen>
   </Emisor>
   <Receptor>
    <RUTRecep>69507000-4</RUTRecep>
    <RznSocRecep>RUT DE PRUEBA PORTAL</RznSocRecep>
    <GiroRecep>Comercial</GiroRecep>
    <DirRecep>Santiago</DirRecep>
    <CmnaRecep>Santiago</CmnaRecep>
    <CiudadRecep>Santiago</CiudadRecep>
   </Receptor>
   <Totales>
    <MntNeto>21888</MntNeto>
    <TasaIVA>19</TasaIVA>
    <IVA>4158</IVA>
    <MntTotal>26046</MntTotal>
   </Totales>
  </Encabezado>
  <Detalle>
   <NroLinDet>1</NroLinDet>
   <NmbItem>SET INTERCAMBIO NUMERO 379791</NmbItem>
   <QtyItem>6</QtyItem>
   <PrcItem>3648</PrcItem>
   <MontoItem>21888</MontoItem>
  </Detalle>
  <TED version="1.0">
   <DD>
    <RE>88888888-8</RE>
    <TD>33</TD>
    <F>52613</F>
    <FE>2013-06-21</FE>
    <RR>69507000-4</RR>
    <RSR>RUT DE PRUEBA PORTAL</RSR>
    <MNT>26046</MNT>
    <IT1>SET INTERCAMBIO NUMERO 379791</IT1>
    <CAF version="1.0">
     <DA>
      <RE>88888888-8</RE>
      <RS>EMPRESA DE PRUEBA</RS>
      <TD>33</TD>
      <RNG>
       <D>17479</D>
       <H>17901</H>
      </RNG>
      <FA>2004-03-30</FA>
      <RSAPK>
       <M>umn8PR3gbC1L3CFheZb5Woh2bj51lvaN2OnwFdTncKXFutekvIAxPmso9DRhgQKJOjlKS1TEKxvzPAYIeEf3tw==</M>
       <E>Aw==</E>
      </RSAPK>
      <IDK>1</IDK>
     </DA>
     <FRMA algoritmo="SHA1withRSA">FVGanT5jYLSopnBQt7+t48aoLtKTYtFZHCV3c2Z2V3XAdExCke7XXONn9N4Lq1BPR24vnH/qCyvIxaYBVCtEMw==</FRMA>
    </CAF>
    <TSTED>2015-04-29T17:11:14</TSTED>
   </DD>
   <FRMT algoritmo="SHA1withRSA">V+YvYUaHFLHuOVg/n5aRxNSgcTkFj2DbGvlH5iyema8h42BNil8f7ewbk7rr5V+a1ShBHcXxU9DjDHWFnQ9p2w==</FRMT>
  </TED>
  <TmstFirma>2015-04-29T17:11:14</TmstFirma>
 </Documento>
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<SignedInfo>
<CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
<SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
<Reference URI="#T35">
<Transforms>
<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
</Transforms>
<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<DigestValue>yvSB5Bnzu2y1lcp6Lf/AxurtfYA=</DigestValue>
</Reference>
</SignedInfo>
<SignatureValue>
VrTsz+2/1ibiHXbV5H8NeBUUIX/SNg6XdLo746w/oZCDlxc61n+nel2bk8mvV9u6dijukupIIPqs
Fk3QLysm3vATCg/SW904M9UbF7k6VUbPfe6fm7pPKYLHd2JHawlTRGNi7ha6EjsGvRzGlisj0/1L
ypQmOPXmbBYVqx/LnfyCovC6eBuj2yuHBVRRo//YcNOBkg2IAjWaPA06MqG/mskcEN0ogjH6Qsh0
3GfFyMKwDCnqmKDfzSOcVOQUcfanaOAnP3Rbr0t74NupJ7MqiETs1A6jnQAOpDCL5gDzJMgw5jNt
+9FNYFx9azEtx5pRvplm6bDvcxmD893xoqnuqw==
</SignatureValue>
<KeyInfo>
<KeyValue>
<RSAKeyValue>
<Modulus>
xUg5RWGM6yKTu1hctQ0J9VZtr6+7VOQ75lDq7MeqxDTJgkHxO+P49GV/hRjLv3rCXvo9JBM8AKj5
U+/uue5OE6PgeqdS+M7HBF4ieD33wVsRYWuu2TLrw+/DRd6yEs61mPVRLDrIqjxxpa41VUAfwPXV
ksCZ7RNklyfSa5D+Zm6sx3v5kGPylWVpdW+k3BFYmUCW2j1rjGb5X9zV9Egi2VGe2SGsYLNu1aJS
HHAIPc+COJIBMENga/syQSNF2l4/GNUkn84RnlW5P75rPg6Oa+y2UwfUgmgrCeMcyJJKDMy6heqm
6huvgaxOTr9DZqWkxJYW5GGWTUUiq64JB3EjOQ==
</Modulus>
<Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
</RSAKeyValue>
</KeyValue>
<X509Data>
<X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate>
</X509Data>
</KeyInfo>
</Signature></DTE></SetDTE>
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<SignedInfo>
<CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
<SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
<Reference URI="#SetDoc">
<Transforms>
<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
</Transforms>
<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<DigestValue>nLalcR+BXsyx4kImaWKQKkc9R1Q=</DigestValue>
</Reference>
</SignedInfo>
<SignatureValue>
q54IE6kZOmQyoP+i+BMJTGQLCw+cfqQNZu1jWARtsJT/yV1rlLcca+vDya+F4KGcwMrQxl0Saxa/
j7c/jriL7JLl6FTqZ1Ae1ESh9RVs+E9vmCBqQAcyofoL7AAN2vz0BxrPEHWWknYoHc6qY2HEXtIq
tQVsMhsA/IWV7DgjdtMoHv4TXCggTc2J5H4HbaLSnNE29nBfYI/PEhSTxqyZToQcZEu6tnr224Am
qY7qWwHAbIN7CiZfsS0oqIPYIodNiXAmC5bKcNFzH8PnvubmkujmgnXoT+vrvzHMNfyKi9p4sMoU
tFtURUy66loNfytaYS/3WgdrMtSonA7aXrU9kQ==
</SignatureValue>
<KeyInfo>
<KeyValue>
<RSAKeyValue>
<Modulus>
xUg5RWGM6yKTu1hctQ0J9VZtr6+7VOQ75lDq7MeqxDTJgkHxO+P49GV/hRjLv3rCXvo9JBM8AKj5
U+/uue5OE6PgeqdS+M7HBF4ieD33wVsRYWuu2TLrw+/DRd6yEs61mPVRLDrIqjxxpa41VUAfwPXV
ksCZ7RNklyfSa5D+Zm6sx3v5kGPylWVpdW+k3BFYmUCW2j1rjGb5X9zV9Egi2VGe2SGsYLNu1aJS
HHAIPc+COJIBMENga/syQSNF2l4/GNUkn84RnlW5P75rPg6Oa+y2UwfUgmgrCeMcyJJKDMy6heqm
6huvgaxOTr9DZqWkxJYW5GGWTUUiq64JB3EjOQ==
</Modulus>
<Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
</RSAKeyValue>
</KeyValue>
<X509Data>
<X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate>
</X509Data>
</KeyInfo>
</Signature></EnvioDTE>
```

It is the same with all DOM vendors: SMSXML, sAdom4XmlVendor and sOXmlDOMVendor

Doing more research I found that it is related to NameSpaces. Actually SETDTE and SIGNATURE belongs to differents NameSpaces that's why I can access SETDTE and can't access SIGNATURE but despite that XML Binding should take care of that. Maybe is there a configuration parameter or something.

Thanks in advance,

A

Comment: Without the XSD, sample XML, and the classes the IDE is generating, it's difficult to say what the problem might be. I've not had issues with loading of XML with the data bindings, but writing has been an issue (complex elements are created out of sequence, for instance, causing validation to fail). What Delphi version?

Comment: Delphi XE7. The XSD is in the link "XSD" in the question. For me complex elements are working ok and I generate the XML at the end, my problem is when I try to reload it to make some changes. I'm editing the question to add an XML example. About the sequence, you are right but with some time I was able to determine the right sequence and it save me a lot of time.

Comment: That XML file looks like it contains rather sensitive information.  Please reassure us that this is not real information.

Comment: Of course this is not real information, that is a test set available for any applicant.